# R - Setting real limits in geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set the axis limits on a `geom_line()` plot made with `R/ggplot2`.

Below I report the simple code:

```
Graph <- ggplot(data=Test,aes(x=Enc1,y=N,group=Trial,colour=Trial)) + 
geom_line(size = 1) + 
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 7)) +
scale_color_manual(values=c('#f92410','#644196')) +
ggtitle("Valutazione peel su provino 50 mm") +  
theme_bw() + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
xlab('Allungamento (mm)') + 
ylab('Forza (N)')
Graph
```

My question is why the axis don't start from the origin but a little below? I would like to see the line starting directly from the bottom/left corner of the graph, but it doesn't.

[image]

Is there any way to adjust this distance? If you like I can also upload the original spreadsheet data file, but I do not know how to do.

Thank you in advance for every reply.

Comment: Just for the future, how can I share it in a topic? Anyhow your comment solved me 100% the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: try `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the parameter `expand` to the `scale_x_discrete` or `scale_x_continuos` (not sure what your x variable is).

```
library(ggplot2)

#generic, reproducible data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, 
                y = runif(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x))+
    geom_line(aes(y = y))+
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) #control axis parameters
```

Comment: It works partially. Thank you for this help. I added also for the y-axis the same: `scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))` and I got the graph starting from the origin as needed but now the problem is that the numbers ofthe axis are lost.

Comment: I solved changing from `scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))` to `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`